# Replacement of Deprecated beanRef() in Camel v2.16.0

Tags: java, apache-camel

We are upgrading from Camel v2.13 to v2.16 and discovered that beanRef() has been marked as deprecated. What is the replacement/alternative recommended by Apache Camel. I was unable to find anything useful on Camel v2.16.0 Documentation site.
Even updated examples are not yet available.

beanRef() is syntax within Java DSL Bean Language of Camel.

Comment: It is very frustrating that the official Camel documentation/example still uses beanref in mid 2017 - http://camel.apache.org/bean.html.  I too have the same question - what is the official recommendation from Apache Camel? The accept answer is not very helpful as I am trying to reference an already instantiated bean (not create a new one).  Has anyone found any official guidance on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume that you are talking about the `ProcessorDefinition` class.

The javadoc comments say to use the `bean(...)` methods as replacements for the `beanRef(...)` methods.

Source reference: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/6dae060eeec8b49531df5d6828030f4ef037f6eb/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/model/ProcessorDefinition.java

Comment: These methods accept an object, not a String referencing the bean.  This changes the paradigm.  Is there any official recommendation for getting an instance of a container-managed bean within the route for use with these methods? The Camel documentation still uses beanref in the examples.

Comment: I suggest that you ask a question

Comment: By the way, did you read this?  http://camel.apache.org/bean.html  I think the "Java DSL bean syntax" section answers your question.

Comment: Thanks, I did here just now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45820387/camel-beanref-deprecated-how-now-to-access-container-managed-beans-in-java-ds/45820449#45820449.  The section does show how to use it with a new Object or one already in the route, however I'm trying to reference a Spring-managed bean specified in the descriptor,  and they don't show how to do this (or retrieve the bean from the container to pass in).  Thanks though.

Comment: In version 2.22 bean() accepts Object so you can pass both String and Bean

Answer (score 4):

```
from(...).to("bean:beanId?method=myMethod")
```

OR

```
from(...).bean("beanId", "myMethod")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of depricated methods of beanRef in Camel 2.16.3

org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.**beanRef(String)**
use ***ProcessorDefinition.bean(Object)***

org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.**beanRef(String, boolean)**
use ***ProcessorDefinition.bean(Object, String, boolean)***

org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.**beanRef(String, String)**
use ***ProcessorDefinition.bean(Object, String)***

org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.**beanRef(String, String, boolean)**
use ***ProcessorDefinition.bean(Object, String, boolean)***

org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.**beanRef(String, String, boolean, boolean)**
***The option multiParameterArray is deprecated.***

Source Reference : http://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.16.3/deprecated-list.html