# Camel .beanRef deprecated - how now to access container-managed beans in Java DSL route?

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

As of Apache Camel 2.16.3 in 2015, all of the .beanRef Java DSL routebuilder methods [have been deprecated](http://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.16.3/deprecated-list.html).

Unfortunately, even in 2017 [the official Camel documentation](http://camel.apache.org/bean.html#Bean-JavaDSLbeansyntax) still says to use the deprecated .beanRef methods.  While the API says to use the .bean(...) methods instead, all of these methods instantiate a new version of the bean or expect an existing one passed in.

My question is, how do I use these methods with the Spring framework to pass in a Spring-managed bean in a Java DSL route and what is the official Camel recommendation?

[This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33632752/replacement-of-deprecated-beanref-in-camel-v2-16-0) was asked in 2015 but the answer is not relevant to my specific question regarding managed beans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.bean("beanRef")`, because if the parameter of the `ProcessorDefinition.bean(Object bean)` method is a String than Camel sets the ref to that bean. ([Relevant source from Camel](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/6dae060eeec8b49531df5d6828030f4ef037f6eb/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/model/ProcessorDefinition.java#L2587))

Comment: Wow good catch, I hope they can update their documentation to make this clearer as I was trying to avoid digging into their source code.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: It is documented in javadoc - https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/model/ProcessorDefinition.java#L2769 - javadoc is up to date with the source code. The website with wiki is being replaced with a new website and documentation for the future where the docs is taken from the source code to minimize maintenance overhead